# When I append a text element to a DOM element, other text inputs lose their value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a form whereby when someone enters a value in a text input, another text input is appended to the form. Here's sample code.

It works, but the text inputs do not retain the values you enter.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Addabox</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var Boxcount=0;
var BaseName = 'roomno';
function AddBox() {
    Boxcount +=1;
    var Fname = BaseName.concat(Boxcount);
    document.getElementById('roomrow').innerHTML += "<input type='text' name="+Fname+" value='' length=4 onchange='AddBox'>";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Add a room</hr><br>
<table>
<tr><td id='roomrow'><input type='text' name='roomno0' value='' length=4 onchange='AddBox()'></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `.concat()` is for arrays, not strings.  You want: `var Fname = BaseName + Boxcount;`

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Strings have a native `.concat()` too.

Comment: P.S. You forgot the `()` in `onchange='AddBox'`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Probably because no one uses it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to us HTML, don't do `.innerHTML += ...`. There are several issues with it, one of which you've discovered here.

Use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` instead.

```
document.getElementById('roomrow').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<input type='text' name="+Fname+" value='' length=4 onchange='AddBox()'>");
```

---

Though I'd prefer DOM creation/manipulation methods.

```
var inp = document.getElementById('roomrow').appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
inp.type='text';
inp.name=Fname; 
inp.value='';
inp.length=4;
inp.onchange=AddBox;
```

Comment: Thank you. I seem to be finding all the hidden Javascript landmines these days. Are using DOM creation/manipulation methods a recommended best practice or a personal preference?

Comment: @user2942256: You're welcome. I'd consider DOM methods to be both a best practice and a personal preference. They're faster and IMO, more idiomatic when working with a DOM *(a hierarchy of objects representing the elements in the document)*. But plenty of people use HTML too. Just avoid `.innerHTML += "..."` syntax like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` copies only the HTML attributes but not properties (that are defined by the DOM). The `value` attribute holds the initial value of the element and any changes are held by the value `property`.

So, if your HTML had an initial value, that would also have been copied. See http://jsfiddle.net/nivas/ucu33/ where the text field has a initial value of `0`.

You can use DOM manipulation (see cookie monster's answer) or JQuery for this.